# Handling relationship in model in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.3

I am learning relationships in Laravel php framework and I am trying to build this query

`SELECT * FROM users u INNER JOIN link_to_stores lts ON u.id=lts.user_id INNER JOIN stores s ON lts.store_id=s.store_id WHERE lts.privilege = 'Owner'`

I built this in Model

Link_to_store.php

```
public function store()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Store');
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

User.php

```
public function store_links()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Link_to_store');
}
```

Store.php

```
public function user_links()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Link_to_store');
}
```

I tried this query but this only joins user and link_to_store table

`$personal_stores = Auth::user()->store_links->where('privilege','=','Owner');`

Now I am confused how to join store table too. Can anyone help with this?

Schema is like this

Stores Table

`store_id store_name`

Users Table

`id name`

Link_to_stores Table

`id store_id user_id privilege`

Comment: Maybe replace `$personal_stores = Auth::user()->store_links->where('privilege','=','Owner');` with `$personal_stores = Auth::user()->where('privilege','=','Owner')->store_links()->store();` Try this and tell me what is output

Comment: `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::store_links()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose `store_links` is actually a pivot table. In this case, you can use [`belongsToMany()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many), this will automatically take care of the pivot table.

To do this, in your `User` model you change the store function to this:

```
function stores() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Store', 'store_links', 'user_id', 'store_id')->withPivot('privilege');
}
```

Because the primary key of `stores` is not `id`, you will have to define this in you Store model with the following line:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'store_id';
```

Now to get the stores for a user, you simply call

```
$stores = Auth::user->stores()->wherePivot('privilege', 'Owner')->get();
```

Comment: I have updated my answer to your database layout, this should make the relation work.

Comment: I am getting this `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'stores.id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select `stores`.*, `Link_to_stores`.`user_id` as `pivot_user_id`, `Link_to_stores`.`store_id` as `pivot_store_id`, `Link_to_stores`.`privilege` as `pivot_privilege` from `stores` inner join `Link_to_stores` on `stores`.`id` = `Link_to_stores`.`store_id` where `Link_to_stores`.`user_id` = 1 and `Link_to_stores`.`privilege` = Owner)`

Comment: Have you added the `$primaryKey` variable to your `Store` model?

Answer (score 0):

> I am learning relationships in Laravel php framework and I am trying to build this query
>
> `SELECT * FROM users u INNER JOIN link_to_stores lts ON u.id=lts.user_id INNER JOIN stores s ON lts.store_id=s.store_id WHERE lts.privilege = 'Owner'`

You are trying to do a join here. You can do a join like this:

```
$stores = User::join('link_to_stores as lts', 'users.id', '=', 'lts.user_id')->join('stores as s', 'lts.store_id', '=', 's.id')->where('lts.privilege', 'Owner')->get();
```

But like Jerodev pointed out, it seems like Many to Many relationship might make more sense in your case. The difference is that relationship will actually execute 2 queries (1 for original model, 1 for relationship). It will then attach the related models to the original model (which is extremely handy).